# How to suppress 'An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.' log message with Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, logging, .net-core, serilog

When implementing my own Exception handler using `app.UseExceptionHandler` with an exception handler lambda / delegate ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-lambda)) I do not want Microsofts [Exception handler middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a9d9f522a907f94fd2935eb26cb321c702de9b50/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs) to log this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

This exception message clutters my log file because I take care of logging the exception with an appropriate LogLevel by myself.

This is how I register my own ErrorHandler:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
                errorApp.Run(ErrorHandler));
```

As described in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19740) filtering *this exact message* and *nothing else* is not possible in a simple way.

How do I filter this exact log message and nothing else from the middleware?

I am using:

- ASP.NET Core 3.1
- Serilog 3.4.0

Comment: Ouch, seems I didn't do my research as good as I thought - thanks for pointing it out. Anyways, the linked answer filters all exceptions from the given context, not only the unwanted exception. Thus I think this question provides a small benefit for everyone searching for this exact problem.
If you think this is not different enough feel free to vote for marking my question as duplicate.

Comment: No, I agree with you. The solution here looks more useful to me. Someone else may come along and close it as a duplicate because the _question_ appears to be the same. I just linked it in because I remember seeing it recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the issue mentioned above, we can use a [Filter expression](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions#filtering-example) for this. Unfortunately the issue only describes a solution for a deprecated package and is filtering all messages from the Middleware, not only the mentioned message.

1. Install the [Serilog.Expressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/serilog.expressions) package
2. Update the matching `appsettings.json` with this configuration:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Expressions" ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "@l='Error' and SourceContext='Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware' and @mt='An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.'"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

3. Make sure you have matching code that loads the configuration from `appsettings.json` [as documented](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#serilogsettingsconfiguration--), e.g.:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
```

This way you can keep all other messages from the `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` and just disable the redundant error log message.

**Side note**: In case the response already has started, our custom exception handler will not be executed - but a warning will be logged and the exception will be rethrown and later logged by another application layer - at least in the application I tested. You can test this behavior by adding this code somewhere before the exception is thrown (`context` is the current HttpContext):

```
 await context.Response.WriteAsync("fish");
```

Comment: If you configure Serilog with `.UseSerilog` then you can add a filter with `configuration.Filter.ByExcluding`, furthermore, if you only care about SourceContext, and don't need the flexibility of `Serilog.Expressions` then you can use `.Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>())` which will just exclude any logs from the ExceptionHandlingMiddleware, but won't do log level or log message matching.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced app.UseExceptionHandler with a custom middleware in my program, it works like a charm.

Startup.cs:

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<HttpExceptionMiddleware>();
```

HttpExceptionMiddleware.cs

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

internal class HttpExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public HttpExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await this.next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            var response = context.Response;
            if (response.HasStarted)
            {
                throw;
            }
            response.StatusCode = (int) e.StatusCode;
            response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Pragma] = "no-cache";
            response.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "-1";
            response.Headers.Remove(HeaderNames.ETag);

            var bodyObj = new {
                Message = e.Message,
                Status = e.StatusCode.ToString()
            };
            var body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(bodyObj);
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(body);
        }
    }
}
```

HTTPException.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;

public class HttpException : Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode)
        : this((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode)
    {
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        this.StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode, string message)
        : this((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode, message)
    {
    }

    public HttpException(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {
    }

    public HttpException(int httpStatusCode, string message, Exception inner)
        : this((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode, message, inner)
    {
    }
}
```